# Merge two tables together in R

Tags: r, merge

Currently I am trying to merge two tables in **R** together. Both of them have different contents and no ID, just the columns have numbers given by **R**.

My problem now is that I cannot add the columns and their values from table 2 to table 1. I also want to mention that both of them have the same amount of rows, which means table 1 has got 1000 rows and and table 2 as well. I also cannot add an ID field otherwise it is not possible to run further steps of my code.

Basically my tables look like this:

[image: Example]

I would really appreciate it, if someone can help me.

Comment: An example would be helpfull. It looks like that `cbind` will do the job

Comment: just use `cbind(table1,table2)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and perhaps blind way) is to use cbind to combine the two tables, as long as the number of rows in each table are equal.

```
x<-tribble(~Value1, ~Value2, ~Value3,

a,b,c,

aa,bb,cc)

y<-tribble(~Value4, ~Value5, ~Value6,

d,e,f,

dd,ee,ff)

cbind(x,y)
```

Output becomes

```
       Value 1      Value 2     Value 3   Value 4    Value 5   Value 6

1            a         b           c         d          e          f 

2           aa        bb           cc       dd         ee         ff
```

Since the two tables are (I assume) mutually exclusive, there is no way to meaningfully join them if you don't have relations to work with. If you seek to merge them in R, it will merge the two tables and return a dataframe that has all the different unique combinations of merging them. This means that, if you have 1000 rows in each, you may end up with a 1000*1000 dataframe.

Comment: Thank you I tried your suggestion and it worked. No I got all of my values in one table.

Answer (score 1):

This will reproduce your example

```
Value1=c("a","aa")
Value2=c("b","bb")
Value3=c("c","cc")
Value4=c("d","dd")
Value5=c("e","ee")
Value6=c("f","ff")

table1=data.frame(Value1,Value2,Value3)
table2=data.frame(Value4,Value5,Value6)  
Result=cbind(table1,table2)
```